# Change the font of apostrophe inside a command

Tags: fonts, catcodes

I can universally change the font of apostrophe `'` using

```
\def\myprime{{\usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}\symbol{39}}}
\catcode`'=\active
\def'{\myprime}
```

But, what I really wanna do is to change it only inside a command. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work. Any help on this?

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\def\myprime{{\usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}\symbol{39}}}
\catcode`'=\active
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{{\def'{\myprime}\color{blue}#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
He's\\
He\myprime s\\
\mycommand{He's}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It seems that there are some related questions, but I'm having a hard time applying them.

Comment: you can not change the catcode of the ' token after it has been parsed as an argument, this why you can not use `\verb` inside a definition,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a “search and replace”:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\newcommand{\pplapostrophe}{{\usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}'}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ' } { \c{pplapostrophe} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

He's

He\pplapostrophe s

\mycommand{He's}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The part `\c{pplapostrophe}` is `l3regex` lingo for `\pplapostrophe`. So we're replacing all occurrences of `'` with the command.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\def`ine an active `'` as an apostrophe in your changed font, but don't change the `\catcode` globally. Then you can always change it locally and thereby "awaken" the definition for as long as you need it:

```tex
{\catcode`'=\active\global\def'{{\usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}\symbol{39}}}
\def\myprime{\catcode`'=\active}
He's,
{\myprime she's,} % changed apostrophe awakened in this {group}
it's
```

Does that solve your problem?